# Is it possible to restore data from Elasticsearch after deleting indices?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I am doing local development on my box and I have deleted some indices that were useful. I wasn't doing any snapshotting, is it possible to restore those indices if I ran the delete command about 5-6 hours ago and it acknowledged with a true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible, if you deleted an index and do not have snapshots of it, you can't recover the data.